# Wordpress - Upload image programmatically, width and height are 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a function which allows users to upload image to my wordpress site. Uploading works fine, but when I open a post with this uploaded image, the image doesn't show up. When I opened it in Firebug I noticed that image width and height is 0.

How can I upload image so it show up like I uploaded it with Media Library form.
This is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["image"])) {
            if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image'];
            $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
            $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides);
            if ($movefile) {
                $wp_filetype = $movefile['type'];
                $filename = $movefile['file'];
                $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                $attachment = array(
                    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename),
                    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype,
                    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'inherit'
                );
                $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename);

                set_post_thumbnail($pageid, $attach_id);

            }
        }
```

Edit:

When I manually add width: 100% in Firebug, the image show up

Comment: So what do your log files say? Would be interesting, because that is where the problem is pointed out.

Comment: @arkascha Where can I find a log. This is my first time making wp plugin.

Comment: Ah, OK. I referred to the log files your http server writes. That is configured inside your http servers configuration. Typically something like /var/log/apache2/.... _if_ you are using the apache http server. Slightly different for other servers, obviously. So: 1. which http server do you use and 2. where are the log files configured?

Comment: @arkascha I found the error logs, but there is nothing from today, so I assume no errors were recorded for this function.

Comment: OK. So next: how does the uploaded file look like inside the file system? Then: what does the network request for the image result in? You can see that in the development console of your browser too.

Comment: In file system it looks normal, I can open it, it's not resized. But in Media Library I can only see the filename, but can't open the image. Also when I upload the image with Media Library I get resized version of the image, but with my function I only have original image.
Also developer console show no errors and I can open image in developer console

Comment: In your question you wrote that you can _not_ open the image in your browsers console...

Comment: @arkascha I can open it in browser console, but width and height are 0 (on page, but in console widht and height are normal). In Media Library I only see image filename, when I click on that image, I get blank space.
I believe reason for this behavious is because my function doesn't create resized versions of the image.

Comment: Should it do so? Can't spot such code... Well, maybe you want to take a debugger and step through the execution then. This helps to understand step by step what is going on inside your script on service side whilst processing the request.

Comment: @arkascha Maybe this will help you to understand what's wrong: http://pastebin.com/BQzGYSDf

Comment: It does not really help, no. But one thing stands out: widths and height are 1, not 0 in there. Now what?

Comment: I didn't see this code at first, I assumed it's 0 because image is not visible and when I manually change css then it's visible

Comment: When you manually change css? What? Sorry, please sit back, tackle this thing yourself. It looks like you do find out things one by one. So it looks like it is more effective if you just make your debugging and understand what is happening. We can be of little help from remote, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.

After the image was uploaded, meta data was not updated. So at the end of this function I added this:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

This code updates the meta data for this image, therefore, Wordpress can find its dimensions.